# difference between sampling from different number system

Tags: random-variables, real-numbers, irrational-numbers, natural-numbers, algorithmic-randomness

Is there any difference in algorithm between sampling from different number system, e.g.sample from a standard Gaussian distribution $X \sim N(0,1)$ with samples defined on rational numbers $Q$ or natural number $N$ or real number $R$ ?

Does the standard pseudo random number generating algorithm fits all different Number System by default? Or one has to develop for every Number systems ? Or sometimes it work sometimes it won’t work?

Comment: Generally not straightforward. Like the normal distribution is defined on reals. So if you want to draw from a normal like distribution on integers you need to discretize the underlying distribution.